# Height for bootstrap text_area not applying properly

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, erb

I have a WIP form I would like to expand a text area for. However, when I apply a height it applies it more like a margin than actual height. If I edit the CSS after the page has been rendered it works properly.

With `height: 12.5`
[image]

Now when I check the console I notice that `height: 12.5rem` is absent. However, if I add it, the page renders properly.

[image]

I am using bootstrap 4 and rails. Relevant code is provided below.

messages.scss

```
#message_form{
  margin-left: 4.0rem;
  // Only visible with smaller screen sizes
  margin-right: 4.0rem;
  margin-top: 2.0rem;
  margin-bottom: 2.0rem;
  width: 50%;
}

.text_form{
  height: 15rem !important;
}
```

_form.html.erb

```
<div id="message_form">
  <%= form_with(model: message, local: true) do |form| %>
    <%# Error message setup %>
    <% if message.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(message.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this message from being saved:</h2>

        <ul>
        <% message.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%# Form setup %>

    <%# Message Title %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= form.label :message_name %>
      <%= form.text_field :message_name, id: :message_message_name, :class=>"form-control" %>
    </div>

    <%# Message Context %>
    <div class="form-group text_form">
      <%= form.label :text %>
      <%= form.text_area :text, id: :message_text, :class=>"form-control" %>
    </div>

    <%# Message send time %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= form.label :date_and_time_to_send %>
      <%= form.text_field :date_and_time_to_send, id: :message_date_and_time_to_send, :class=>"form-control" %>
    </div>

    <%# Actions to perform %>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= form.submit 'Send Now', :class=>'btn btn-primary btn-block'%>
      <%= form.submit 'Save to Database', :class=>'btn btn-primary btn-block'%>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

How can I fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: It's a simple case of not targeting the desired element. You're applying `height` to the parent element. Give `.text_form textarea {height: 12.5rem;}` a shot. Important: no need for `!important`

Comment: Things are changing tho. Without the `height: 12.5rem` there is no large space between the next field. I can apply other styling as well.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Thanks for the edit. That works. Is the reason for the double selection so that I actually select the box and not the outside of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're targetting the parent element. Try this instead:

```
.text_form textarea {
  height: 12.5rem;
}
```

Resource if you need more help with text area elements: https://css-tricks.com/textarea-tricks/